# Pandas map to a new column, SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas data frame, I'm trying to map df['old_column'], apply user defined function *f* for each row and create a new column.

```
df['new_column'] = df['old_column'].map(lambda x: f(x))
```

This will give out "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." error.

I tried the following:

```
df.loc[:, 'new_column'] = df['old_column'].map(lambda x: f(x))
```

which doesn't help. What can I do?

Comment: In pandas 0.19.2 this warning appears no longer to be raised in this circumstance

Comment: I'm still getting this warning in 1.2.0

Comment: The warning actually explicitly says to try using `.loc` instead, but when following that advice the warning is still raised. Quite confusing. (version 1.2.0)

Answer (score 19):

A `SettingWithCopy` warning is raised for certain operations in `pandas` which may not have the expected result because they may be acting on copies rather than the original datasets. Unfortunately there is no easy way for *pandas itself* to tell whether or not a particular call will or won't do this, so this warning tends to be raised in many, many cases where (from my perspective as a user) nothing is actually amiss.

Both of your method calls are fine. If you want to get rid of the warning entirely, you can specify:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

See [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) for more information on this.

Comment: I suggest putting a `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'warn'` after the triggering statement, to catch possible true positives of this warning in your subsequent code.