# Using df['C'] vs. df.loc[:, 'C'] to assign new column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1,10, 10), 'B':np.random.randint(1,10, 10)})

def sumf(row):
    result = None
    if row['A']>= row['B']:
        result = row['A'] - row['B']
    else:
        result = row['B'] - row['A']
    return result

df.loc[:,'C'] = df.apply(sumf, axis = 1)
df['D'] = df.apply(sumf, axis = 1)
my_var = 'zero'
df['E'] = my_var
```

What would be the difference in terms of view/copy for column `C` and `D`? And is it the right way to fill column `E` with `zero`?
I have a similar data frame with the same data and logic (just in another jupyter notebook), but there I am getting a warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:19:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

When I try these lines:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(sumf, axis = 1)
my_var = 'zero'
df['E'] = my_var
```

Comment: I dont get this error. Is there another piece of code your are running that's causing this error upstream?

Comment: Sorry, didn't figure out how to post formatted code as a comment. So my production code is the same (except column names, type of calculation and the data). And I don't get the warning also (when I run the code above) but I do get this warning when I run my production code.

Answer (score 0):

The `SettingWithCopyWarning` is a warning related to the possibility of chained assignment. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) on "Returning a view versus a copy", it states "The chained assignment warnings / exceptions are aiming to inform the user of a possibly invalid assignment. There may be false positives; situations where a chained assignment is inadvertently reported."

I am not able to reproduce this warning when running your code (with `pandas==0.23.4` and `Python 2.7.15`). Possibly you are running a different version of `pandas`? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105859/pandas-map-to-a-new-column-settingwithcopywarning) seems to indicate that this is a `pandas` version issue. Likely if you upgrade your `pandas` version, the warning will not appear, and both ways to assign a new column (`df.loc[:,'C']` or `df['C']`) are valid. Make sure your versions of `python`, `pandas` and `numpy` are upgraded and the same in your different environments.

In your case, the warning is certainly a false-positive situation, since you are defining new columns in your original dataframe (not using a copy of the dataframe).

And, yes, if you want to fill column `E` with the string `zero`, this is an appropriate way to do so.